# MySQL JOIN two tables with only one row and an attribute for each entry

Tags: mysql, join

there are two tables in my database, which I am trying to join:

**Example of table "posts":**

```
id | author | title
21 | 1      | This is my post.
22 | 2      | I am another title.
23 | 3      | And yet another post.
```

**Example of table "usermeta":**

```
meta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value
1       | 1       | name     | John Doe
2       | 1       | zip-code | 12345
3       | 1       | status   | premium
4       | 2       | name     | Steve Jobs
5       | 2       | zip-code | 22499
6       | 2       | status   | basic
```

---

Now after experimenting around for the last few hours, I am back to my initial query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN usermeta ON posts.author = usermeta.user_id
WHERE posts.author = 1
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
id | author | title                 | user_id | meta_key | meta_value |
21 | 1      | This is my post.      | 1       | name     | John Doe   |
21 | 1      | This is my post.      | 1       | zip-code | 12345      |
21 | 1      | This is my post.      | 1       | status   | premium    |
```

However I'm trying to get this:

```
id | author | title                 | user_id | author_name | author_zip | author_status |
21 | 1      | This is my post.      | 1       | John Doe    | 12345      | premium       |
```

What else can I try in order to achieve said result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.author, p.title,
       max(case when m.meta_key = 'name' then m.meta_value end) as author_name,
       max(case when m.meta_key = 'zip-code' then m.meta_value end) as author_zip,
       max(case when m.meta_key = 'status' then m.meta_value end) as author_status
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN usermeta m ON p.author = m.user_id
WHERE p.author = 1 
GROUP BY p.id, p.author, p.title
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helps me. I didn't know about CASE in MySQL.

Is there a way to have two conditions in a WHEN?
 - - - -
Example: CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'name' AND m.meta_value IS NOT NULL THEN m.meta_value END

Comment: Just like that. Try it

Comment: Ah allright, I got it working now. I forgot the GROUP BY clause, which resulted in either only one result being returned alltogether or a result for each meta_key (3 per user).